# How to avoid [Disqus] Discussion duplication when using Pagination?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having problem with Disqus + laravel pagination. I have a post model where a post have minipost and for each post i want it to contain 5 minipost.. when I navigate to the 2nd pagination page the Disqus Discussion got auto generated for the 2nd page.. How can I avoid this duplication?

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
    var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = route('home');
        this.page.identifier = $slug; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };

    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

    s.src = '//testblog.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

The query

```
$posts = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail()->minipost()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Disqus will always see the url and will provide the content accordingly.. However you should see the way to override this

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen how can i do that? are there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve it directly

Because disqus will provide the comment content according to your url.

During the pagination, probably your url will change and you can't stop it.

At the same time as you wanted to show only the same disqus content throughout all the pages in url.

You should do some tricky way to do it.

**Way 1 :**

Have the Pagination and all the content in iframe, So that the url won't change

**Way 2 :**

Use Jquery Datatables or some other plugins related to it, and customize it a bit better to have your desired look

**Way 3 :**

Explore the disqus code and hardcode the url for that particular page

Like

```
this.page.url = "http://someurl.com/#!" + id;
```

Hope this helps you